# Assign value to numpy array with overlaid slices of indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I want to assign a value to some segments of an array. 
I've got indexes of the segments as tuples (start_idx, end_idx). 
Segments may overlay or be sub-segments of each other.

```
a = np.zeros(12)
segments = np.array([(0, 3), (1, 2), (6, 8), (8, 10)])
a[segments] = 1
```

The results is:

```
a
>> array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

How can I mask all segments to get this output:

```
a
>> array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Are you sure the desired output is correct? It seems like the `[3]` element is wrong?! Shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: @MSeifert It seems its inclusive of the segment ends.

Comment: @Divakar But how should `10` be handled then? Normally it would be an `IndexError` at least for `a = np.zeros(10)`.

Comment: @MSeifert Guessing that's a typo : `a = np.zeros(12)` as the final output seems to have 12 elems.

Comment: @Divakar Ah, that's a possibility as well. But seems like the answers exclude the end point - at least the accepted one. So I thought the desired output may be wrong (but wrong input would make sense too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to simply loop through the *segments*, and convert *ranges* to actual index:

```
a = np.zeros(10)
segments = np.array([(0, 3), (1, 2), (6, 8), (8, 10)])

a[[i for s in segments for i in range(*s)]] = 1    
a
# array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one vectorized approach with the idea being borrowed from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45058046/3293881) -

```
def segment_arr(segments, L): # L being length of output array
    s = np.zeros(L,dtype=int)
    stop = segments[:,1]+1
    np.add.at(s,segments[:,0],1)
    np.add.at(s,stop[stop<len(s)],-1)
    return (s.cumsum()>0).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [298]: segments = np.array([(0, 3), (1, 2), (6, 8), (8, 10)])

In [299]: segment_arr(segments, L=12)
Out[299]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: At least *one* solution that actually produces the "given expected output". :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = np.zeros(10)
segments = np.array([(0, 3), (1, 2), (6, 8), (8, 10)])
a[range(3)+range(1,2)+range(6,8)+range(8,10)] = 1
print (a)
```

Comment: How can I do that without assigning them manually? I can create ranges in a list generator, but how to feed them?

Comment: Well in that case you will have to Loop through

Comment: Note that this throws a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'` on python-3.x

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention the trivial solution: Use a `for`-loop over the `segments` and assign to the slices:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(12)
segments = np.array([(0, 3), (1, 2), (6, 8), (8, 10)])

for seg in segments.tolist():  # the "tolist" is just an optimization here, you *could* omit it.
    a[seg[0]: seg[1]+1] = 1    # or just "seq[1]" if you want to exclude the end point
print(a)
# array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.])
```